# Returning UserName using PowerShell and Windows Event Viewer from when a service was stopped and started

Tags: windows, events, powershell, service

If we look at the local Windows Server System EventViewer, I can see that I restarted the service Apache Tomcat..

[image]
However, I have a daily report that runs that shows nothing for the USER. And, what we would want is to show either "SYSTEM" or "DOMAIN\USER" or "USER" would be fine.

```
$time = [System.Management.ManagementDateTImeConverter]::ToDmtfDateTime((Get-Date).AddHours(-24))
   $TomcatEvents =     Get-WmiObject Win32_NTLogEvent -ComputerName $servern -Filter "LogFile='system' AND (Message like '%Tomcat%') AND (EventCode=7036)  AND (TimeWritten >= '$time')" |
    select @{n="Server";e={$servern}},Logfile,Type,User,@{name='TimeWritten';Expression={$_.ConvertToDateTime($_.TimeWritten)}},SourceName,Message,EventCode | sort-object TimeWritten -desc
```

I have also tried the following:

```
$time = (Get-Date).AddHours(-24)
Get-eventlog -computername SERVER_NAME -logname System | Where-Object { $_.EventID -eq 7036 -and $_.TimeGenerated -gt $time -and $_.EntryType -eq 'Information' -and  $_.Source -eq "Service Control Manager" -and $_.Message -Like '*Tomcat*' } |
select TimeGenerated,MachineName,EventID,@{n='Account Name';e={$_.ReplacementStrings[-7]}},@{n='Domain Name';e={$_.ReplacementStrings[5]}},@{n='Caller Computer Name';e={$_.ReplacementStrings[1]}},EntryType,Message | 
convertto-html | out-file c:\test.html
```

which does not work either..  Let's see how replacement strings shows...

```
Get-EventLog -LogName System -EntryType Information -Newest 10 | Where-Object { $_.EventID -eq 7036 } |
  Select-Object -Property * |
  ForEach-Object {
     $_.ReplacementStrings = $_.ReplacementStrings -join ','
     $_.Data = $_.Data -join ','
     $_    
  }
```

Replacement Strings is shown below:

```
EventID            : 7036
MachineName        : SERVER_NAME
Data               : 
Index              : 207410
Category           : (0)
CategoryNumber     : 0
EntryType          : Information
Message            : The Apache Tomcat 6 service entered the running state.
Source             : Service Control Manager
ReplacementStrings : Apache Tomcat 6,running
InstanceId         : 1073748860
TimeGenerated      : 11/21/2014 8:08:48 AM
TimeWritten        : 11/21/2014 8:08:48 AM
UserName           : 
Site               : 
Container          :
```

Answer (score 0):

I was using the wrong EVENT ID..  Use 7035 (I was using 7036) to get the correct results.

For Example:

```
$time = [System.Management.ManagementDateTImeConverter]::ToDmtfDateTime((Get-Date).AddHours(-24))
   $TomcatEvents =     Get-WmiObject Win32_NTLogEvent -ComputerName $servern -Filter "LogFile='system' AND (Message like '%Tomcat%') AND (EventCode=7035)  AND (TimeWritten >= '$time')" |
    select @{n="Server";e={$servern}},Logfile,Type,User,@{name='TimeWritten';Expression={$_.ConvertToDateTime($_.TimeWritten)}},SourceName,Message,EventCode | sort-object TimeWritten -desc
```

Hope this helps!